# Retrieve content from DOM->getElementById without element id

Tags: php, html, domdocument

When using

```
$body = $dom->getElementById('content');
```

The output is the following:

```
<div id=content> 
  <div>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to remove the `<div id=content></div>`part.
Since i only need the inner part, excluding the div with id content

needed result:

```
<div>
   <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

My current code:

```
$url = 'myfile.html';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($file);
//$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$body = $dom->getElementById('nbscontent');
$stringbody = $dom->saveHTML($body);
echo $stringbody;
```

Comment: Can we use js here?

Comment: I know how to do a work around with java-script, but i would like not to use it at this point of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getElementById`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) returns a [`DOMElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) which has the property [`childNodes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) which is a [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). You can traverse  through that to get the children and subsequently the `innerHTML`.

```
$str = "<div id='test'><p>inside</p></div>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);    
$body = $dom->getElementById('test');

$innerHTML = '';

foreach ($body->childNodes as $child) 
{ 
    $innerHTML .= $body->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
}

echo $innerHTML; // <p>inside</p>
```

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/SoreJoyousApplets)